# How can i make menu in KivyMD like this:

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I need to make menu when only icons are visible when minimized:
[image]

And then i open menu: [image]

I try to make this to combine MDTopAppBar and MDNavigationDrawer but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the `MDNavigationRail`.

See the [KivyMD documentation](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/navigationrail/index.html) for more details and [this example](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/navigationrail/index.html#example) in particular.